# Bootstrap - wrong column on screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I creating simple post list with thumbnails.
I have created this code:

```
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">
                            <div class="news">
                                <div class="news-thumb text-center">
                                    <img src="images/NewsThumb.png" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="news-excerpt">
                                    <p>
                                        Content
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">
                            <div class="news">
                                <div class="news-thumb text-center">
                                    <img src="images/NewsThumb.png" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="news-excerpt">
                                    <p>
                                        Content
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

but on FullHD (1920px) I getting values for col-sm-* - why?
http://prntscr.com/an1097

Answer (score 1):

This is because there is no over-riding column offset above for viewports above col-sm. Meaning that your page will display as the 6 central columns with the three column offset - even on larger screens.

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
```

you will need to add the following (col-md-offset-0) to each of the parent divs to prevent the offset in -md and -lg and to allow the two divs to display side by side:

```
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-offset-0">
```

I just tested this and it now works and displays the columns side by side - look at the code snippet in action (in full screen mode - the columns are adjacent and in the small window they stack vertically. Note that I added coloured backgrounds to demonstrate the point.

```html
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-offset-0" style="background:red">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">
                            <div class="news">
                                <div class="news-thumb text-center">
                                    <img src="images/NewsThumb.png" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="news-excerpt">
                                    <p>
                                        Content
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-offset-0"  style="background:blue">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">
                            <div class="news">
                                <div class="news-thumb text-center">
                                    <img src="images/NewsThumb.png" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="news-excerpt">
                                    <p>
                                        Content
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```